# heating a evacuated steelcase with water inside

Tags: thermodynamics, water, vacuum

the set is like this:

- A) a stellcase 5 cm x 5 cm (or 2'' x 2'') (Variable S)
- A.a) half of the volumen in the steel case is water (Variable W)
- B) a heating device (Variable H)

Water in an evacuated device seems to evaporat at roomtemperature.

***Questions:***

Q1: What happens in the moment we evacuate the Steeldevice S?

Q1.1: Will the Case S burst or is there a formula to adjust the device (thickness of walls) that it will not burst?

Q2: Will the potential energy generated from the device in vacuum and heated be bigger than if there wouldn't have been a vacuum?

Q2.1: Is there a way to "use" the energy generated from the "HEATED" device. Since there is a vacuum it seems the absorbation of the energy has somehow to be transported by material. Which implications are known?

***Assumption no vacuum (simple closed Steelbox with half water) but airtight***

Q3: What would happen if we heat the fixed device to arround 100°C?

Q3.1: If it would tend to burst is there a formula to calculate the required thickness of the stellbox to withstand?

Q3.2 How does the potentical energy generated by heating the device compare to a vacuumized (evacuated) environment

Thanks for answering for an undergraduate student the sleep-stealing questions?